# What's the difference between盛名and名副其实

Tags: meaning

I have the sentences 这个学校名副其实的温暖，这学校对外声称自己是暖心的社团，接触他的人也确实感受到暖暖的爱
名副其实 means"reputation"or"not just in name only，but also in reality"

Comment: This is the first time I saw 溫暖 being used to describe a school. Also the first time to see a school being described as a 社團. 接觸他????接觸 a school??? Who wrote these sentences? A pupil?

Comment: 温暖可用来形容人、事、物。比如:温暖的家，温暖的举动，温暖的人；社团指社会上的团体，用来代指学校可能是不够恰当；接触除了有“挨着并碰到……接近并碰到……”的意思外，还有“与某人、某团体、某团体中的一人或多人来往；与……交流。”的意思。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

名副其实 is similar to "live up to one's name" in English.

And below is the mapping character by character.

```
名：fame
副：matches
其：its
实：reality
```

Alternatively, you could say 名不符实 to say the exact the opposite.

Comment: 名：fame/ (also name - something that's as described in its name)

Comment: Thank  you  for  your  answer